# C# Graphics missing

Tags: c#, canvas, graphics

I recently tried to make a WPF application with Visual Studio 2013 (compiling against .NET 4.5) . I wanted to draw something on a canvas. But the method doesn't work.

```
private void drawSomething(Graphics g)
```

I took some old code I used with Windows Forms when I noticed that my Graphics wasn't found anymore. First I thought I forgot the using directive but I used

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Still Graphics couldn't be found. I was reading on the web that some people had to add a reference to the project. I did this and added the reference manually. Still it doesn't work.

So I start wondering. Has this changed? Haven't used C# for a while.

Hopefully someone knows what to do.

Comment: What's telling you that `Graphics` cannot be found?  Does it not compile or are you getting an Intellisense warning?

Comment: It is the normal "the type or namespace 'Graphics' could not be found" message. Can't import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual Studio, you can right click on Graphics and then choose the option named 'Resolve' The IDE will list you available assemblies for you to import one of them.

If you can't see the RESOLVE option, figure you need to add a manual reference to your project...

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I already tried to correct the using directive. Still that seems to be another problem.

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong dll You can download another here [link](http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_drawing_dll.html)
add reference to it

Be Careful: I don't know if That link is trusted or not. 
Reinstalling the MicroSoft .Net FrameWork is painful but the trusted solution

Comment: Okay I didn't see you were using WPF! Sorry!

In WPF, you replace your `Graphics` class with `DrawingContext` object

Comment: Ah okay, so there is no Graphics for WPF? That explains a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Of course there are! But You must consider some of the following "How to" topics from MicroSoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750780%28v=vs.110%29.aspx